# Objective C: Keep Image After App Termination

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsdata

I am making an app that downloads files from an online server by clicking an Icon representing the file to be downloaded, then the file will be saved to the app's sandbox.

I have managed to do those mentioned above. Now, what I want to do is to put a "Check" image on the icon to allude the user that it is already downloaded.

I already tried it by putting another `UIImageView`on top of the icon when the download is successful but when I fully terminate the app and re-open it, the image is gone and I need to download it again to show it.

How will I able to that?

Comment: If you have saved the downloaded image files in documents directory. There is no chance those files get deleted automatically.

Comment: You didn't show *any* code so how can anyone guess what you're doing, let alone doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep an array of all the downloaded files, and at startup check to see which files to apply the check mark to.

For example:

When you get the image:

```
NSMutableArray *array;
array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"downloaded"].mutableCopy;
if (!array) array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:somethingToIdentifyTheImageBy]; //For example, a string with the name of the image
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"downloaded"]
```

On startup:

```
NSArray *downloadedImages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"downloaded"];
forin (NSString *string in downloadedImages)
{
    //Apply check mark
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to Save your Downloaded Image to `Library` Directory of Device and Retrive it, as `NSUserDefaults` will not allow you to store Large amount of Data.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = paths[0];

NSString *imageFilePath =  [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImageIcon.jpg"];

NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imageFilePath]) {
    // File Exist at Library Directory, Just Read it.
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath];
}
else
{
    // File Doesn't Exist at Library Directory, Download it From Server
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR Image File URL"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSString *imagePath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
    NSLog(@"Image Stored At %@",imagePath);
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save anything inside the app's bundle, but you can store the image in your app's documents directory by using [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] method. This is not exactly permanent, but it stays there at least until the user deletes the app.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myImageURL];
NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/myImage.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```